# Doxygen doesn't correctly generate code spans or code blocks

Tags: markdown, documentation, syntax-highlighting, doxygen

I have the following markdown snippet in a markdown file in my documentation:

````
```cpp
/**
 * Input Description:
 *
 * @depth_test: true
 * @topology: line list
 * @line_width: <float value>
*/
```

The `Input Description:` header is necesary and it is case sensitive. Also, there can only be one such comment per shader group and it must be put on the vertex shader of that group.

The valid values for `@topology:` are:
````

This is how it's formatted in a regular markdown explorer:

[image]

This is how it comes out in Doxygen:

[image]

The documentation:
https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html#md_codeblock
Says code can be formatted by indenting it by at least 4 spaces (and indeed this does "work" except there's no language specific syntax highlighting.)

I guess I can live with that, but it also explicitly says code spans are supported and the code spans are not being formatted properly.

Is it possible to get syntax highlighitng for code blocks in doxygen?
How do I fix the code spans?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: My version is 1.8.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a code block with triple backticks (```` ``` ````) doxygen sees the part as a code block analogous to a file generated with `SOURCE_BROWSER = YES` / a code snippet (`\snippet`) or an inline code block and thus honors the setting of `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS`. When setting `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS` to `YES` the doxygen relevant comment blocks (like `/**`) are not shown in the output only the normal comment blocks (like `/*`). Setting `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS = NO` will solve the problem.

From  the documentation (https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_strip_code_comments):

> STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS
>
> Setting the STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS tag to YES will instruct doxygen to hide any special comment blocks from generated source code fragments. Normal C, C++ and Fortran comments will always remain visible.

The output with `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS = NO`:

[image]